Doubt regarding formation of Hall voltage in a large conductor
Suppose a surface current is flowing in a sufficiently large conducting plate through space with constant uniform magnetic field throughout. How will hall effect be developed here? Would not the electrons just move in circles (or helices) and not be deposited on the sides of the plate generating the Hall voltage? I understand how it might be developed in regions with non-uniform magnetic field (it might taper off at the edges, thus enabling charge buildup there), and in wires (which might not have sufficient width to facilitate a circular motion). What am I getting wrong?

You may want to look into the Shubnikov-de Haas and quantum Hall effects. Under the right conditions, you can say that the electrons are moving in circles (roughly speaking).
